# jQuery if else statement issue

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to get this if else statement to run but I can only seem to get one half of the if else statement to work.

```
$("#og").click(function () {
    if ($('#og').data('clicked')) {
        //#og element clicked run function #1
        $("#about").click(function () {
            $("#about").animate({ 'top': -1130 }, 2000);
            $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': -1120 }, 2000);
            alert("running click code")
        });
    } else { //#og element not clicked run function #2
        $("#about").click(function () {
            $("#about").animate({ 'top': -1190 }, 2000);
            $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': -1170 }, 2000);
            alert("running no click code")
        });
    }
});
```

I want to check if a div(#og) has been clicked. If it has I want it to animate #about and #aboutform to a position when #about is clicked. If #og has not been clicked I want it to animate #about and #aboutform to another position when #about is clicked.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Please create a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would always evaluate to `true`, since you're setting the `data` of the element before the condition.

Comment: Is this an attempt at a toggle function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit of what you're attempting to do, I think this would be a better solution. Binding event handlers in event handlers is generally not the best approach:

```
$('#og').click(function() { $(this).data('clicked', true); });

$('#about').click(function() { 
    var aboutTop = -1190;
    var aboutFormTop = -1170;
    if ($('#og').data('clicked')) {
        aboutTop = -1130;
        aboutFormTop = -1120;
    }

    $("#about").animate({ 'top': aboutTop }, 2000);
    $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': aboutFormTop }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. This is what I was attempting to do. I will have to study this a bit more to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

you set `$(this).data('clicked', true);` and then you immediately check if the click value is true or not.  It looks to me like you will never see that second `else` block happen since you never set clicked to false.

Answer (score 3):

This does not make sense to me:

```
$("#og").click(function () { // clicked
    $(this).data('clicked', true); //assign true 
    if($('#og').data('clicked')) { //question if true? you just assigned true to it
```

This will not go to else.

Answer (score 1):

The code above only executes when $("#og") is clicked, thus within the function $(this) is always $("#og").  Since you are always setting 'clicked' to true on $(this) the condition involving $("#og") will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here. It seems you're listening to a click event on #og, however the event will only be triggered if there's a click, so it's unclear why you check for the data attribute clicked to be set to anything.

It should be sufficient for you to just do:

```
$('#og').click(function() { // do things on click
});
```

There will be no case where anything is fired if it's not clicked.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have logic error in your code:

> $("#og").click(function(){});

this function is callback for a click event. So when the user clicks element #og this function is called. What you are trying to do is run some code when user didn't clicked #og (I assume) inside callback function for clicking #og. That doesn't make sense at all.

I think better approach would be running some code until the user clicked #og element and then run some other code.